# Export Excel (.xlsx) file to CSV separated with commas

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

I am using Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus.  When I save my document as CSV, I end up with values separated with semi-colons, but I really need commas.

I tried changing Windows Regional Settings to put a different list separator, but excel doesn't take it.

Also, when I do a Save As, I have two choices of CSV in the drop down (comma or semi-colon separator) but both end up with semi-colons as the separator.

How do I fix this?  (please don't ask me to do a search and replace...)

Comment: AFAIK, that separator is, indeed, dependent on the `list separator` in the Windows Regional Settings. On the `Numbers` tab under `Additional Settings`.  Are you sure you hit `Apply` or closed the dialog box, after typing in the comma as the list separator?

Answer (score 1):

Try [this advice](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-to-change-semicolon-to-comma-when-saving-csv/cf7c9537-82da-448d-9516-82f3a4b13fae):

```
 Select File -> Options -> Advanced. Clear the check box 'Use system
 settings'.

 Set 'Decimal separator' to a point (dot), and 'Thousands separator' to
 a comma. Click OK.

 Export to CSV.

 Select File -> Options -> Advanced. Tick the check box 'Use system
 settings'. Click OK
```

Comment: no luck, still semi-colons...